# How to split a txtbox.Text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Textbox with a datepicker, and when I change the date at the calendar it fires the event textchanged.

I need to split the text (date) in the Textbox to just get the year of this date.

Comment: you might try String.Format()

Comment: Why don't you use the `DateTimePicker.Value`? `int year = dateTimePicker1.Value.Year;`.

Comment: because i need to call another method after this event

Comment: I don't understand why the fact that you need to call another method has any bearing on how you get your year. If you absolutely need it as a string, you could go `string year = dateTimePicker1.Value.Year.ToString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(txt);
time.Year;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your handler could look like this:

```
protected void YourTextBox_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var theDate = DateTime.Parse(YourTextBox.Text);
    var theYear = theDate.Year;
}
```

Even though you're using a datepicker to set the value, you'll want to handle the case where a user provides a non-date value and `Parse()` fails.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the `DateTimePicker.Value`?

```
int year = dateTimePicker1.Value.Year;
```

This is more efficient, more concise and less error-prone.

However, if you only have text, use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.TryParse`:

```
int? year = null;
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out dt))
    year = dt.Year;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(txtbox.Text);
var year = date.Year;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string dateExample = yourDateObj.ToString("d");
string[] dateSplit = dateExample.Split("/");
```

dateSplit[2] will be the year.

Comment: Will not work if the cultures date separator is not /. Also, using date.ToString and then String.Split is really evil. Just use date.Year.

Comment: True! if you change the format from "d" to something else, you'll need to change the .Split. ..and I'm an evil kinda guy >:)

Comment: No, the "d" Format specifier will use the current cultures date separator which is in most countries not / but something different. So the split will fail.

Comment: Didn't think of that! Good call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `txtbox.Text.Split(char)` with whatever your calendar uses as the delimiter.

For example, if your calendar sets dates like 2013-10-16, call Split with `'-'` and use the first result, so `txtbox.Text.Split('-')[0]`. If it looks like 10/15/2013, then call with `'/'` and use the third result, so `txtbox.Text.Split('/')[2]`.

Parsing as a date may or may not work depending on how ambiguous your calendar's output is.